# How to explode by using a column value?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to get a dynamic version of `org.apache.spark.sql.explode` working with no luck: I have a dataset with a date column called `event_date` and another column called `no_of_days_gap`. I want to use `no_of_days_gap` to create clones of the row using the `explode` function. One of my first attempts was to use this:

```
myDataset.withColumn("clone", explode(array((0 until col("no_of_days_gap")).map(lit): _*)))
```

However, `col("no_of_days_gap")` is of type `Column` and an `Int` is expected. I also tried various other approaches. So how can I get this working?

P.S.: I managed to get an alternative solution working using a `map` function followed by calling `flatMap`, however, I am really interested in understanding how to get the `withColumn` approach working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following?

```
scala> val diddy = Seq(
     |   ("2017/03/07", 4),
     |   ("2016/12/09", 2)).toDF("event_date", "no_of_days_gap")
diddy: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [event_date: string, no_of_days_gap: int]

scala> diddy.flatMap(r => Seq.fill(r.getInt(1))(r.getString(0))).show
+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|2017/03/07|
|2017/03/07|
|2017/03/07|
|2017/03/07|
|2016/12/09|
|2016/12/09|
+----------+

// use explode instead

scala> diddy.explode("no_of_days_gap", "events") { n: Int => 0 until n }.show
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
+----------+--------------+------+
|event_date|no_of_days_gap|events|
+----------+--------------+------+
|2017/03/07|             4|     0|
|2017/03/07|             4|     1|
|2017/03/07|             4|     2|
|2017/03/07|             4|     3|
|2016/12/09|             2|     0|
|2016/12/09|             2|     1|
+----------+--------------+------+
```

If however you insist on `withColumn`, so...be...it! *Buckle up!*

```
diddy
  .withColumn("concat", concat($"event_date", lit(",")))
  .withColumn("repeat", expr("repeat(concat, no_of_days_gap)"))
  .withColumn("split", split($"repeat", ","))
  .withColumn("explode", explode($"split"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use udf:

```
val range = udf((i: Integer) => (0 until i).toSeq)

df
  .withColumn("clone", range($"no_of_days_gap"))  // Add range
  .withColumn("clone", explode($"clone"))  // Explode
```

Comment: In spark-shell this returns an error: 

```scala> val range = udf((i: Integer) => (0 until i).toSeq)
scala.MatchError: scala.collection.immutable.Range (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:692)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:671)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3072)
  ... 48 elided```